# Linux and the Fender Mustang GT guitar amp series

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, usb-audio

Note: To ward off any of the inevitable confusion that can arise here it is important to distinguish the old series of Fender Mustang amps (has plenty of support and info on the internet) from the **GT** series. I am asking about the **GT** series here.

TL;DR The Question:

- Does anybody have specific knowledge or experience that can help me get the Mustang GT series of amps working in Linux? If so, please recommend a general procedure to get the features of this amp working with Linux.

---

More context:

I am transitioning from Windows to Linux (continually delighted and happy the FOSSier I get) and getting as much as I can working of my old setup as I can.

One thing I could do in Windows was record audio using my Fender Mustang GT as an audio interface. It has a USB out.

I want to attempt to configure it for recording in Linux.

I am looking for high quality and low latency and will want some recommendations on what to use be it Jack / ALSA / PulseAudio, whatever.

I currently have Ardour installed and Audacity.

Please help, I'm using NixOS 18.03 and comfortable with getting into configs and compiling things and all that. I've used various distros I just have less experience with Linux audio since I always used to do my music production in other OSes. Think that is about to change.

Thanks!

Comment: Please focus your question further. In stackexchange the requirement is one question per question, and you have at least three questions bundled together. In short: use JACK.

Comment: Try plugging the amp into the USB port and then check `dmesg` to see if it mentions anything about `snd-usb-audio`, which is the USB audio module. NixOS uses pulseaudio by default, so if the device registers as a USB audio device, you can do a quick test by: running `audacity` then select Edit -> Preferences -> Devices and choose the amp as the recording device. This is not going to give you the lowest latency recording (that's what JACK is for) but it will test whether the amp can be used as an audio source on Linux.

Comment: There is a package `mustang-plug` in ubuntu repo, see also this for further configuration step http://lifeofageekadmin.com/install-plug-linux-software-fender-mustang-fedora24/

Answer (score 1):

I have a Fender Mustang GT40 that I use with Ubuntu Studio. When the amp is connected to the computer via USB, the audio outputs show up in Carla, and I'm able to connect them to the inputs of other plugins that handle digital audio inputs. It's working quite well. I did nothing on my computer other than plug in the USB connector.

If you aren't familiar with setting up the parameters in the Studio Controls interface, or in Carla, I would strongly recommend familiarizing yourself with them. If you want more details, I may be able to help.